# Why can't I use an Intersection type here but spreading one type into another works?

Tags: flowtype

Today I found out that I can do the latter here, but not the former, and I can't figure out why.

This does NOT work:

```
type User = {| id: number |}
type ExternalUser = User & {| externalUser: boolean |}

checkUser = (user: User | ExternalUser) {
    if (user.externalUser) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

But this does:

```
type User = {| id: number |}
type ExternalUser = {| ...User, externalUser: boolean |}

checkUser = (user: User | ExternalUser) {
    if (user.externalUser) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

In the first example, flow tells me `externalUser` does not exist in `User` on the `if` statement check. What am I missing? Seems like the end result should be the same. Possible Flow bug or am I breaking a rule that I'm not aware of?